# The view newsletter.views.control_newsletter_edit didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

This is my urls.py :

```
from django.urls import path
from newsletter.views import control_newsletter, control_newsletter_list, control_newsletter_detail, control_newsletter_edit

urlpatterns = [
    path('newsletter/', control_newsletter, name='control_newsletter'),
    path('newsletter_list/', control_newsletter_list, name='control_newsletter_list'),
    path('newsletter_detail/<int:pk>/', control_newsletter_detail, name='control_newsletter_detail'),
    path('newsletter_edit/<int:pk>/', control_newsletter_edit, name='control_newsletter_edit'),]
```

and this is my view.py :

```
def control_newsletter_edit(request, pk):
    newsletter = get_object_or_404(Newsletter, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = NewsletterCreationForm(request.POST, instance=Newsletter)

        if form.is_valid():
            newsletter = form.save()

            if newsletter.status == 'Published':
                subject = newsletter.subject
                body = newsletter.body
                from_email = global_settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
                for email in newsletter.email.all():
                    send_mail(subject=subject, from_email=from_email, recipient_list=[email], message=body,
                              fail_silently=True)
                messages.success(request, 'Your Changes Write Successfully.',
                                 'alert alert-success alert-dismissible')
            else:
                messages.warning(request, 'SomeThing Went Wrong..',
                                 'alert alert-warning alert-dismissible')
            return redirect('control_newsletter_detail', pk=newsletter.pk)

        else:
            form = NewsletterCreationForm(instance=newsletter)

            context = {
                'form': form,
            }

            return render(request, 'control_panel/control_newsletter.html', context)
```

when I try to access to `newsletter_edit/1/` 
from here in my teplate code :

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <a href="{% url 'control_newsletter_edit' pk=newsletter.pk %}">
                    <button class="btn-success">Edit</button>
                </a>
            </div>
```

I faced to this error :

```
ValueError at /panel/newsletter_edit/1/
The view newsletter.views.control_newsletter_edit didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

I checked my urls.py and my views.py over and over but I cant find out what is my problem.
is any body know why I face to this error?
**In addition, I'm sorry for writing mistakes in my question.**
and if you need the full of my views.py , pleas tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is here `if request.method == 'POST':` as you can see you're only returning a template when the request method is post, make sure you return something outside the if conditional

Comment: yes, my that was my problem, thank you sir.I just make a mistake and put else:
           `form = NewsletterCreationForm(instance=newsletter)

            context = {
                'form': form,
            }

            return render(request, 'control_panel/control_newsletter.html', context)`
with extra spcae and when I remove it, it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what should happen if a request other than `HTTP POST` comes. It can be done by using a simple **`else`** block as below,

```
def control_newsletter_edit(request, pk):
    newsletter = get_object_or_404(Newsletter, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = NewsletterCreationForm(request.POST, instance=Newsletter)

        if form.is_valid():
            newsletter = form.save()

            if newsletter.status == 'Published':
                subject = newsletter.subject
                body = newsletter.body
                from_email = global_settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
                for email in newsletter.email.all():
                    send_mail(subject=subject, from_email=from_email, recipient_list=[email], message=body,
                              fail_silently=True)
                messages.success(request, 'Your Changes Write Successfully.',
                                 'alert alert-success alert-dismissible')
            else:
                messages.warning(request, 'SomeThing Went Wrong..',
                                 'alert alert-warning alert-dismissible')
            return redirect('control_newsletter_detail', pk=newsletter.pk)

        else:
            form = NewsletterCreationForm(instance=newsletter)

            context = {
                'form': form,
            }

            return render(request, 'control_panel/control_newsletter.html', context)
    else:
        form = NewsletterCreationForm()  # if method not HTTP POST
    return render(request, 'control_panel/control_newsletter.html', {"form":form})
```